# Expressing a sequence with two sigma notation

Tags: sequences-and-series

To express (1-p_0) + (1-p_0-p_1) + (1-p_0-p_1-p_2) + ...

I initially thought:

Sum from n=0 to infinity [1 - (sum from m=0 to infinity(p_m)]

But I'm having trouble seeing it that's true. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Notice that each term may be written as a sum:

$$1-p_0=1-\sum_{k=0}^0 p_k, \ \ 1-p_0-p_1-p_2=1-\sum_{k=0}^2p_i,$$

and so forth. You can see an arbitrary term may look like

$$1-\sum_{k=0}^m p_i, m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}.$$

Can you conjecture how you might express the sum of all such terms?

Comment: $\NN$ does have zero. You don't need to add it.

Comment: @ogerard Not always.

Comment: Yes - I had figured out the sum for an arbitrary term. My guess was summing again that sum for an arbitrary term from 0 to whatever I was going to. So:

Comment: @ogerard I added it to avoid the possibility that swimspaz14 does not include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$. I personally do not consider $0$ a natural number. I suppose I could write $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ instead.

Comment: Sigma from 0 to m of [1-(sigma from 0 to m of (p_i)] where m is natural numbers including 0

Comment: I believe you have the right idea, but your response is not correct as you have written it.

Comment: Oh I just saw your earlier comment. Consider now that what changes in each term is $m$.

Comment: I understand that the final product is going to look something like m-m*p_0-(m-1)*p_1-(m-2)*p_2-...-2*p_(m-1)-p_m. I just am having trouble understanding how to build that from the bottom up with sigma notation

Comment: You should not have a product. What your wrote in your question is $$\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^0 p_i\right)+\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^1 p_i\right)+\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^2 p_i\right)+\cdots+\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^m p_i\right)+\cdots$$ which is then $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^m p_i\right).$$